# show popUp only if a click in a button and reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, woocommerce

I am doing a website using Wordpress and Woocommerce.

Each time that I add a item to the car (click in add to cart) the page reload and show a message with the item that I add to the car.(popUp with info)

My problem is that if I reload the page (F5 the browser) I see the popup again without clicking in the button "add to cart"

There is one way to show the PopUP, only if I click in the "add to cart" button  and reload the page..

I try this but don't work

```
$('single_add_to_cart_button').on 'click', () ->
  if document.addEventListener 'DOMContentLoaded', (event) ->
  styles = 
  'display': 'inline'
  'opacity': '1'
  'background-color': '#000'
  $('.modal.fade').css styles
```

Any idea!!

thank in advice!

Comment: You could look into using session storage or cookies

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
<div id="event-modal" class="modal ">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" href="#" onclick="$('#event-modal').hide()">x</a>
    <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some information</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="btn primary" href="#">Primary</a>
    <a class="btn secondary" href="#">Secondary</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<button id="popup"  onclick="$('#event-modal').show()">Open PopUp</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bharoo Jangid but I can use this solution, because when I click in the button the page is reload, so I have to show the popUp before reload.